# Document validity in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, document, validation, time-out

I have some documents which are valid only for 3 months. It consists of some tax rates.Is there any possibility to show that the uploaded document is valid only for 3 months and further it should be deactive or an message should pop up to request for new tax rates.

Answer (score 0):

I think a custom expiration policy could solve your issue, as described [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e18a8/custom-expiration-policy-in-sharepoint-2013/) or [here](http://www.future-processing.pl/blog/retention-policy-in-sharepoint-2013/). In your custom solution you can send a mail / assign a task to the last editor / creator of the document when it is older than the desired lifetime.

You can change a status flag on the document itself that you can use on the UI to filter the documents and / or assign conditional formatting rules / icons (like exclamation mark) to it.

You can create a custom document content type and assign the expiration policy to it (recommended), or you can assign it directly to the the doc. library if you wish to keep it simple.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, it is at risk of being converted to a comment. I recommend you to add information from your attached link to your post and just make it clear that it is cited content